# Calculate storage capacity of RAID 2 / 3 / 4?

Tags: raid, storage

Given `n` drives and capacity `s` of each drive, how would I calculate storage capacity for RAID 2 / 3 / 4?

For example, I know RAID 5's storage capacity can be calculated with the following formula:

```
(n - 1) * s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### RAID 2

A [RAID 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_2) stripes data at the bit (rather than block) level, and uses a [Hamming code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) for error correction. This code uses **m** parity bits out of **2<sup>m</sup> - 1** bits therefor the storage capacity for **n** disks would be **2<sup>m</sup> - m - 1** where **m** = **log<sub>2</sub>(n+1)**. Here are some possible scenarios:

| Parity disks | Total disks | Storage capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 1 * s |
| 3 | 7 | 4 * s |
| 4 | 15 | 11 * s |
| 5 | 31 | 26 * s |

#### RAID 3

A [RAID 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_3) uses byte-level striping with a dedicated parity disk, so the capacity is **(n - 1) * s**.

#### RAID 4

A [RAID 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_4) uses block-level striping with a dedicated parity disk, so again the capacity is **(n - 1) * s**.